# toggling same div with multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple buttons above a div which when clicked use

```js
//jquery code
$("#conainerZero").hide();
$("#one-bt").click(function(){
$("#containerZero").load("file/anyfile.html");
$("#contanerZero").toggle();
}
```

```html
<div id="contentContainer">
<button id="one-bt">first button</button>
<button id="two-bt">first button</button>
<button id="three-bt">Third button</button>
<hr>
<!--below is the div in which i want to use load content by jquery .load() method-->
<div id="containerZero"></div>

</div>
```

My dilemma is that when I click a different button to load different content to the div with the id containerZero, and then go back to click the first button I have to click it twice to get it, I assume it's because it was on show before I clicked different button and then came back to the same button.

Comment: I think you need to use .show() aftear .load(), rather than toggle. And you might want to use .hide() before .load()

Comment: `toggle()` will change state, so if you previously toggled it visible, the next trigger will hide it. use show/hide instead of toggle. you also have your first selector misspelled which may be why it's not hiding it initially.

Comment: what suppose `.toggle()` to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethings you need to do

**1st**: use `data` attribute

**2nd**: no need for `containerZero` if you used `display:none` for it on css

**3rd**: use `load` callback function to show the div after completely loaded

**4th**: wrap your code inside `$(document).ready()`

**5th**: add a class for your button to not run the function again when click it multiple time

**6th**: use same class for all buttons and make one `click` instead of using three `click` one for each button id

So your code should be something like this

On HTML

```
<div id="contentContainer">
  <button id="one-bt" class="loadContent" data-url="file/anyfile1.html">first button</button>
  <button id="two-bt" class="loadContent" data-url="file/anyfile2.html">Second button</button>
  <button id="three-bt" class="loadContent" data-url="file/anyfile3.html">Third button</button>
  <hr>
  <!--below is the div in which i want to use load content by jquery .load() method-->
  <div id="containerZero"></div>

</div>
```

On CSS

```
#containerZero{
  display : none;
}
```

On Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click' , '.loadContent:not(.active)' , function(){
       var getfile = $(this).data('url');
       $('.loadContent').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       $("#containerZero").hide().load(getfile , function(){
           $("#containerZero").slideDown();
       });
  });
});
```

This is the Demo *sure I ignore the `.load()` part*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click' , '.loadContent:not(.active)' , function(){
       var getfile = $(this).data('url');
       $('.loadContent').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       /*$("#containerZero").hide().load(getfile , function(){
         $("#containerZero").slideDown();
       });*/
       
       
       // for test
       $("#containerZero").hide().html(getfile);
       $("#containerZero").slideDown();
  });
  $('.loadContent').eq(0).click();
});
```

```css
#containerZero{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentContainer">
  <button id="one-bt" class="loadContent" data-url="file/anyfile1.html">first button</button>
  <button id="two-bt" class="loadContent" data-url="file/anyfile2.html">Second button</button>
  <button id="three-bt" class="loadContent" data-url="file/anyfile3.html">Third button</button>
  <hr>
  <!--below is the div in which i want to use load content by jquery .load() method-->
  <div id="containerZero"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: "Mohamed-yousef"-Thank you brother man, this certainly is useful.

Comment: @SiyadNijah you're welcome .. but only one thing .. when I tried the demo the code not listen to `:not(.active)` so your code may run `click` event each time you click the same button .. I'll try to solve that and I let you know .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: @SiyadNijah I got the point you need to use `$(document).on('click' , '.loadContent:not(.active)' , function(){` instead of `.on('click')` with this your click function will not run with multiple click for same button .. Good Luck :-)